# Not able to create tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from Tkinter import *
root=Tk()
frame1=Frame(root)
frame2=Frame(root)
str=StringVar()
text=Text(frame2,width=5,height=20)
def response():
    b=text.get("1.0","END-1c")
    str.set(b)
text=Text(frame2,width=5,height=20)
button=Button(frame2,width=3,height=3,text="SEND",command=response)
text.pack(side=LEFT)
button.pack(side=RIGHT)
label=Label(frame1,width=10,height=50,textvariable=str)
label.pack()
frame1.pack(side=TOP,fill=X)
frame2.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=X)
```

This Python code I have written on Gedit.  When I try to invoke the python code using terminal command no window appears on the screen.  What can be the reason for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On some systems, you need to call the [`Tk.mainloop`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.mainloop-method) method at the end of your program:

```
root=Tk()
...
root.mainloop()
```

Doing so starts the Tcl interpreter and establishes the window.

Comment: To be a bit more pedantic, `mainloop` is always required. However, some interactive environments such as IDLE will do that for you automatically. If you want your script to be able to run standalone, you must call `mainloop`.